How to connect to informix database using jdbc jar file in python
Any ideas how to connect to informix database using jdbc jar file in python?
I tried jaydebeapi:
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver',
                          myurl,
                          ['user', 'pass'],
                          jdbc_driver_path
                         )

# ... then rest of code that selects data from table

When I execute myscript.py, it only displays logs before this connection and nothing else; it looks like silent failing.

Have you considered asking the author of the JayDeBeApi module?

Why not use java for connecting with jdbc
